# Two listView same page Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I am trying to put two list views in the same page with Yii2 but whenever I change the page in one the second change too. Any suggestions? I searched everywhere and haven't found any similar issues although I think it's very basic. Any help?

Comment: you need different page_param i guess. Without code there is no help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I've edited your question to improve grammar and clarify wording but I'm not sure what do you mean by "whenever I change the page in one the second change too". Should it be "whenever I change the first list view on the page page the second changes too"? Please use the "edit" button to clarify that yourself. Also please show us your code like Insane Skull has suggested. Best regards

Comment: please show the code of your view and controller action

Answer (score -1):

```
  In controller you may pass two data provider for the two list views this may help 
  you to solve this

  public function actionView($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        $reportsToUserDataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $model->parent()
        ]);


        $reporteeDataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $model->children(),
            'pagination' => false,
        ]);
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('alert', [
                'options' => ['class' => 'alert-success'],
                'body' => 'Your Reportees has been updated successfully'
            ]);
        }

        return $this->render('view', [
                'model' => $model,
                'reportsToUserDataProvider' => $reportsToUserDataProvider,
                'reporteeDataProvider' => $reporteeDataProvider,
]);
}
```